# use regex on html tags but keep delimiters

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to split up a string of html tags from a rich text field in my database into ordered tags and words. I want to keep the delimiters in order so I can rebuild the string. I'm using language translation APIs to convert the words.

```
String original = "<b>hello!</b><br><br><b><u>this is an example</u></b><br>";
String reg = "(?=<(“[^”]*”|'[^’]*’|[^'”>])*>)";
String[] conversion = original.split(reg);

for(String token : conversion) {
    System.out.println(token);
}
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
<b>hello!
</b>
<br>
<br>
<b>
<u>this is an example
</u>
</b>
<br>
```

Which is super close. I tried using Lookbehind regex `(?=<(“[^”]*”|'[^’]*’|[^'”>])*>)|(?<=<(“[^”]*”|'[^’]*’|[^'”>])*>)` but I run into an error "Invalid regex: Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 62". Its pointing at this section:

```
(?=<(“[^”]*”|'[^’]*’|[^'”>])*>)|(?<=<(“[^”]*”|'[^’]*’|[^'”>])*>)
                                                              ^
```

I'm trying to get this output for each line:

```
<b>
hello!
</b>
<br>
<br>
<b>
<u>
this is an example
</u>
</b>
<br>
```

I'm newer to regex and this all looks like witchcraft to me. Anyone know any Java-friendly lookbehind or techniques to accomplish this?

Comment: Oh, thats simpler. that worked. If you list it as an answer, i'll mark it top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split with an empty location before `<`, after `>` BUT not when at the start of the string:

```
original.split("(?!^)(?:(?<=>)|(?=<))")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h2NhB2/1). *Details*:

- `(?!^)` - make sure the position is not at the start of the string
- `(?:(?<=>)|(?=<))` - either of the two:

  - `(?<=>)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a position that is immediately preceded with a `>` char
  - `|` - or
  - `(?=<)` - a positive lookahead that matches a position that is immediately followed with a `<` char.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/K1Tw53):

```java
String original = "<b>hello!</b><br><br><b><u>this is an example</u></b><br>";
String separator = "(?!^)(?:(?<=>)|(?=<))";
String[] results = original.split(separator);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(results));
```